# can't create an objectMapper in java

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I am creating an instance of the object mapper.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

This line gives me the following error:

> The constructor ObjectMapper() is undefined

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also provide the import statement for `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Check the ObjectMapper class (or it's documentation) which builders or constructors it provides

Comment: Maybe, the `ObjectMapper` does not have a standard constructor, just one (or more) that take parameters...

Comment: import org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

Comment: Remove the line `import org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper;`. You want `ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library, not from Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing the below jar if you are using Jackson

```
jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.0.jar
```

Also try importing below package

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use fasterxml jackson ObjectMapper then there is an empty constructor:

```
/*
/**********************************************************
/* Life-cycle: constructing instance
/**********************************************************
 */

/**
 * Default constructor, which will construct the default
 * {@link JsonFactory} as necessary, use
 * {@link SerializerProvider} as its
 * {@link SerializerProvider}, and
 * {@link BeanSerializerFactory} as its
 * {@link SerializerFactory}.
 * This means that it
 * can serialize all standard JDK types, as well as regular
 * Java Beans (based on method names and Jackson-specific annotations),
 * but does not support JAXB annotations.
 */
public ObjectMapper() {
    this(null, null, null);
}
```

This is copied from the JavaDoc. Please make sure that the Import statement is correct. I am using

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check libraries in your class.

If you imported other library having same name by mistake, it will cuases a problem..

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

The first line should be deleted in above example.